# COMANDO 'AS' DO SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados

Boa noite!

Então pessoal, tenho uma tabela onde a mesma possui algumas colunas, dentre estas: data_atual e data_validade, assim que é feito um cadastro é gerado uma coluna auxiliar através do comando AS do sql, essa coluna auxiliar guarda a informação 'valida' ou 'invalida' dependendo do resultado apos o cadastro das dadas, por exemplo se data_atual for menor que data_validade a coluna recebe 'valida' caso contrario recebe 'invalida' ate aí tudo certo, o lance ta na hora de pesquisar o resultado da coluna auxiliar com a comando LIKE, tipo em certo momento queria trazer somente o resultado 'valida' e em outro 'invalida' no entanto não tou conseguindo, alguem pode da uma força?

Answer (score 2):

O comando AS do sql não gera uma nova coluna. Ele serve  apenas para criar um alias (atalho) para algum atributo de sua tabela ou resultado de uma expressão na querie. É muito útil quando temos queries em duas ou mais tabelas relacionadas para evitar colisão entre atributos com o mesmo nome. Um exemplo :

```
SELECT C.NOME_PAGINA,CAT.LINK_CATEGORIA,CAT.STATUS,C.ID_CONTEUDO,C.STATUS FROM 
CONTEUDO C INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS CAT ON CAT.ID_CATEGORIA = C.ID_CATEGORIA
```

Na querie acima ambas as tabelas tem o atributo **STATUS** para não gerar confusão podemos fazer :

```
SELECT C.NOME_PAGINA,CAT.LINK_CATEGORIA,CAT.STATUS AS CAT_STATUS 
,C.ID_CONTEUDO,C.STATUS AS CONTEUDO_STATUS FROM 
CONTEUDO C INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS CAT ON CAT.ID_CATEGORIA = C.ID_CATEGORIA
```

Criamos um nomes fictícios temporários **CAT_STATUS** e **CONTEUDO_STATUS**  para acessar o retorno de dados. Existem outras situações que também precisamos lançar mão de utilizar o **AS**.

Portando dentro de sua tabela deve haver o suposto atributo **auxiliar** mencionado em sua pergunta para que você possa filtrar os resultados que deseja por ele. Agora se o seu  alias **Auxiliar** é um resultado  condicional gerado pela querie e não existe o atributo na tabela e deseja filtrar por ele. Poderia resolver como no exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1
FROM MyTable
WHERE SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3) = 'MySearch'
```

Apenas repetindo a expressão no WHERE.